# Apparently (!) inconsistent signing between .NET and Mono; Mono signing is not idempotent

Tags: c#, mono, cryptoapi

Google Cloud Storage provides Java, C# code samples for generating signed URLs:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#signing-code-csharp

I'm using the code sample. With the same service account|key, bucket and object, the Java code and the C# code (on Windows) work. When I try the C# code on Mono/Linux, it does not work. The error is:

```
Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
```

Injecting some debugging code corroborates this error.

Here's the augmented method that does the signing:

```
private String signString(String stringToSign)  {
    if (key == null) throw new Exception("Certificate not initialized");
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters(
        24,
        "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider",
        ((RSACryptoServiceProvider)key.PrivateKey).CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName
        );
    RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
    byte[] rawSignature = provider.SignData(buffer, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
    Console.WriteLine ("signature == ");
    Console.WriteLine (BitConverter.ToString(rawSignature).Replace("-", string.Empty));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(rawSignature);
}
```

I expect (perhaps incorrectly that) repeated calls to signString with the same string value, would return the same rawSignature and result. On Java and Windows, this is true. On Mono, the value changes

```
String testString="helloworld";
Console.WriteLine("Signing '" + testString + "' == " + this.signString(testString));
Console.WriteLine("Signing '" + testString + "' == " + this.signString(testString));
Console.WriteLine("Signing '" + testString + "' == " + this.signString(testString));
```

returns, abbreviated results:

```
signature == 
4415768E8E2FB862...
Signing 'helloworld' == RBV2jo4v...
signature == 
95E589C2F8DAD7ED...
Signing 'helloworld' == leWJwvja...
signature == 
0589E4454FE4FB3A...
Signing 'helloworld' == BYnkRU/k...
```

With Java, a similar test using the Google sample returns:

```
rawSignature == 
3E56F09EE9CF7D98...
Signing 'helloworld' == PlbwnunP...
rawSignature == 
3E56F09EE9CF7D98...
Signing 'helloworld' == PlbwnunP...
rawSignature == 
3E56F09EE9CF7D98...
Signing 'helloworld' == PlbwnunP...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code aims to use Microsoft provider which never exists on Mono and Linux.

Comment: Thanks @lex-li. Why aren't errors raised when running on Mono/Linux? Why is the application of signString to the same string non-idempotent? Is there an equivalent that works for Mono/Linux? Is there an equivalent that works x-platform? Thanks!!

Comment: First, Google probably won't support Mono at all. Second, .NET Core 5 is coming and Google might support that next year. If you do want to use Mono, you will have to see deeper into the sample code from Google on what exactly it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get consistent results by not using `CspParameters` at all, but using the `PrivateKey` property of `X509Certificate2`. My current "portable" implementation unfortunately requires a cast which makes me nervous, but it does appear to give the same results on Windows and Linux (under Mono 4.0.2), and those are the same results as the original sample code. Here's a short test app which works under Mono:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var key = new X509Certificate2("key.p12", "notasecret");
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test string");
        // This is the slightly dodgy bit...
        var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) key.PrivateKey;
        byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(buffer, "SHA256");
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(signature));
    }
}
```

As noted in comments, this *doesn't* work under .NET, for unknown reasons :(

Now I *haven't* tried using this to make any Cloud Storage requests yet, but I expect it would work.

On more modern platforms, you can use the fact that `RSA` has a [`SignData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt132675(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and use the [`GetPrivateRSAKey()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an `RSA` instance:

```
var rsa = key.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var signature = rsa.SignData(
   buffer, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

You may be able to use this on Mono too depending on which version you target.

Comment: Strong progress. Thanks very much!

Comment: With "SHA256", .NET throws "Invalid algorithm specified" on the SignData method. Mono (4.0.3) generates consistent (yay!) signatures but Google still reports "...signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. ...". I will compare with that generated by Java because they look to be the same. With "HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1", .NET (again) throws "Invalid algorithm specified". Mono throws "Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0".

Comment: @DazWilkin: Agh - sorry, only checked that the Mono version was equivalent to what the version using `GetPrivateRSAKey` did on my machine. That version definitely worked for me (Windows 10, compiled from the command line) - it's odd that it didn't work for you on .NET. (I can understand it not working on Mono.)

Comment: @DazWilkin: It feels like there are two things we need to work out: a) why GCS is reporting a problem with the signature; b) how to generate the signature on both platforms. If the Java code is producing the same signature, I'm very surprised at a). I've tried a few things now, but can't work out why b) is a problem...

Comment: Busy for an hour but will then look into this again. The signature for "helloworld" is the same between .NET, Mono and Java. So, it is weird that it does not work. It is likely the source of the signature I'm generating has a 'quirk' so will look there. No idea why it doesn't work on .NET (using Xamarin Studio on Windows), will try from VS.

Comment: @DazWilkin: If you're using Xamarin Studio on Windows, it may well be executing in Mono anyway. Try running the generated executable straight from the command line...

Comment: FYI: XS on Windows by default targets .Net. To debug Mono on Windows inside Xamarin Studio you need to change active runtime via Project->Active Runtime->Mono.

Comment: Within Xamarin Studio, I'm forcing the runtime with Run, Run With and then choosing .NET or Mono /cc @david-karlaš

Comment: @DazWilkin: Right. So which version of .NET are you using? I'm still surprised that the version using HashAlgorithmName etc doesn't work :(

Comment: .NET 4.6. If I force it down to 4.5/4, I get an error "The name 'HashAlgorithmName' does not exist in the current context" (same-same for 'RSASignaturePadding'). The error is not manifest under 4.6

Comment: More progress.. The sample does a PUT-GET-DELETE. I commented out the PUT+DELETE and GET works for Mono. I confirmed that the PUT URL is identical (weo .NET|Mono drop the "https://" prefix (but this makes no difference) but, for some reason the PUT does not work on Mono (no error just blocks) and does work on Java. So, there appears to be something else going on.

Comment: Partial success ;-) On a Linux (Ubuntu) machine w/ Mono 3.2.8 using Jon's first recommendation, it works perfectly (PUT+GET+DELETE). The same code is blocking on Mono 4.0.3 (?) on PUT on Windows but GET works.

Comment: @DazWilkin: Wow. Weird. If it weren't HTTPS, I'd suggest using Wireshark or something similar to look at the difference between network requests. It feels like this has now moved beyond the hashing part though... the sample code doesn't dispose of the WebResponse, which I'd expect to lead to hanging on the *third* request made due to connection pooling, but given that the PUT is the *first* request, it shouldn't be a problem there. Still, it may be worth modifying `renderResponse` to dispose of the response. (I'll see if I can get the sample fixed...)